# Cannot Play Video error in PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-videoview, popupwindow

Hi I am trying to play video in PopupWindow but I am getting this error. I am able to play the same video directly in my activity. 
I found lot of queries related to Cannot Play video but none of them helped me in resolving this issue.
Can any one help. 
Thanks

In my activity.java file I am adding a popupWindow

```
    private PopupVideoView mPopupVideoView;


    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
    mPopupWindow.setContentView(mPopupVideoView.getView());
    mPopupWindow.setHeight(360);
    mPopupWindow.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

In  PopupVideoView.java
This gives me a view which contains a videoview and start playing the video as soon as i call getView().

```
    public View getView() {

    if (mPopupVideoView == null) {
        mPopupVideoView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.videoview_popup, null);
        mVideoView = (VideoView)mPopupVideoView.findViewById(R.id.popup_videoView);
    }

    String uri= "android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(uri);
    mVideoView.start();

    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e(mContext.getPackageName(), "Error Occured");
            return true;
        }
    });

    return mPopupVideoView;

}
```

in android 2.3.3 video is audible but not visible and in ICS its not even audible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184364/android-video-hear-sound-but-no-video look at this

Comment: @RobinHood yes i have seen this. I am running it on device and video is playing properly in activity but not in popupwindow

Comment: @Swati can you share your popupwindow class?

Comment: I am using android PopupWindow

Comment: PopupVideoView this one.

Comment: already added the getView method of that. apart from that there are just variable declaration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23504/discussion-between-swati-and-robinhood)