# Android :play video in PopupWindow

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VideoView invisible in Popupwindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889526/videoview-invisible-in-popupwindow)

I am making a function that moving VideoView with finger.

As I use common layout such that RelativeLayout as VideoView's parent,the video palys   normally.

But it blinks too much when moving along finger.

So I thought that PopupWindow may conquer this problem.But the VideoView which added in PopupWindow just leave a transparent space and audio plays normally.

I have searched many answsers,unfortunately there is no one for me.

can a video be played in PopupWindow?

How do I solve the blink problem?

[A similar question located here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889526/videoview-invisible-in-popupwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889526/videoview-invisible-in-popupwindow)

Comment: Did you try using custom dialog as a popup window ?

Comment: Could you try this, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/PopupVideo.apk. If it is ok i will send to you source.

Comment: Sorry,the link you given could not be opened in my network area.Could you email me the APK or source .I will really appreciate it! mjyok12345@gmail.com

Comment: I found the apk.And this is the one for me! Could you email me the source! @talhakosen

Comment: mjyok12345@gmail.com  haha ,sorry   @talhakosen

Comment: hi did you solved this problem