# How to play mp4 video files, android

Tags: android, android-intent, actionview

I tried the following code. But unable to play mp4 files using ACTION_VIEW. But I am able to play m4v files. How to play mp4 files.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri data = Uri.parse(filePath);
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Errors...? LogCat...? Any Force close...? anything else happening on the screen...?

Comment: In any case, this post might help: [StackOverflow:Android not playing mp4 video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167608/android-not-playing-video-mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue is with streaming of video file with certain file types. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I found the alternate solution as to down fiel into sdcard and then play the file from SD-Card

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo