# Video not appearing on a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I has a app that loads a url on a WebView.

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

web.loadUrl(lastUrl);
```

But a spot that should has Video first shows a "loading" view than disappears, if a tap on it occurs, the sound of the video starts playing but not show.

PS: I came across answers that told to add the hardwareAccelerated flag on Manifest, but this solutions simply does not work here.

Comment: In the android manifest, set android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true) as well with hardwareAccelerated="true" and it's working.

Comment: Hey there,
I have tested some websites, Videos are shown in Android PIE but is not shown in Android Lolipop... And your solution also not work

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184364/android-video-hear-sound-but-no-video) question and the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167608/android-not-playing-video-mp4) from slytron?

By the way setPluginsEnabled is deprecated in favor of [setPluginState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29) as of API level 8.

Comment: Yeah.. i did see that questions, but they are specific to an embedded VideoView and not the WebView. PS: setPluginState give the same result as before.

Comment: Can't see any issues with your code and I guess you tested on a real device. Can you give some more info? What's the video format, player, tested API level, HTML (<video> or <embed>)? Does your web content work on non Android WebKit browser? Did you try different videos? Is the [Adobe Flash Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer) installed on your test device?

Comment: I tested on a device. The native browser renders the same video. And I'm not sure about video format and other things, it's just happens on all that videos revistaalfa.abril.com.br/videos/